# What is ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

What is ADO.NET and what difference between it and SQL Server?

Comment: I think this question should be closed.

Comment: @vulkanino: I don't. It may be obvious to you and me, but not necessarily to beginners or people coming from a different background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET is a .NET technology designed to make writing code against the database more easy.

It's not a database (SQL Server is a Database server), it's a tool used to access a database. ADO.NET last incarnation comes with "Entity Framework", an Object Relational Mapper (an other tool designed to make the developper life easier too)

Answer (score 1):

ADO.net is more like an API included in the .net library , to allow programmers to access relational (or sometimes non relational databases) through code. That is , it frees programmers from the necessity of interacting directly with the database. It is more like a wrapper for all the SQL actions you might do in the SQL server .

Comment: I would say that it is a tool *for* interacting with the server.  Not that it frees the dev from directly interacting with the database (only the db gets to directly interact with the data, evething else does so indirectly).